# Replace a string of characters to " " in a data frame column using R function

Tags: r, dataframe

[Screenshot of the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBLWT.png)

I want to replace everything after the first _ in `data77298$SAMPLE.CODE` to " ", such that I get levels to be GSM2048265, GSM2048266 etc.,

Is it possible using a single command to change all strings after the underscore to null?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at these tips on how to produce a [minimum, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as this post on [creating a great example in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Perhaps the following tips on [asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be worth a read.

Comment: It helps to post the example input text directly in your question

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by `gsub`

```
my_string<-c("GSM2048265_Somet_323_h4554ing_here","GSM2048266_sometwewe_sdsd_hing_here")
gsub("\\_.*","",my_string)
[1] "GSM2048265" "GSM2048266"
```

Comment: That helps! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
library(stringr)
my_string<-c("GSM2048265_1_2_£_$_F_CA","GSM2048266_aasv_vaerv_vasd", "GSM2048266_arvqb_oyor_1234")
word(my_string, 1, sep = "_")
```